# jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js always returns false on form submit so form is not posting the data to server side

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I am using MVC 5 and in that project I have a form for password change and that form using the data annotation attributes of the viewmodel to validate the fields. For that I am using jquery.validate.js with jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js. Here are the codes in below. so my question is why it $('form').valid() always return false on form submit?
IN web.config all seems ok and this is happening in all the forms through out the applciation.

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <!-- UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled - Enable client side JavaScript validation using jQuery Validate. -->
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />    

public class MyPasswordViewModel
    {
        [Display(Name = "New Password:")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "New password is required.")]
        public string NewPassword { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Confirm Password:")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Confirm password is required.")]
        [Compare("NewPassword",ErrorMessage = "Both the password Fields should be same.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

        public int TabId { get; set; }

        public string Email { get; set; }
        public bool IsSuccess { get; set; }
        public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is the view

```
using (Html.BeginForm("MyPassword", "UserArea", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            <h1>Manage Password</h1>
            {
                Html.RenderPartial("_UserAreaTabs", Model.TabId);
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.ErrorMessage))
            {
                <p class="@(Model.IsSuccess ? "text-success" : "text-danger")">@Model.ErrorMessage</p>
            }
            <div class="form-horizontal">

                <div class="alert alert-info">
                    Password is case-sensitive and may consist of a-Z, 0-9, underscores(_) and be between
                    6-20 characters.
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NewPassword, new { @class = "control-label col-sm-3" })
                    <div class="input-group col-sm-4">
                        @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.NewPassword, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-3 text-danger">
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NewPassword)
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "control-label col-sm-3" })
                    <div class="input-group col-sm-4">
                        @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-3 text-danger">
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword)
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-3">
                        <input type="submit" name="name" value="Update" class="btn btn-primary" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            @Html.ScriptBundle("validatejsbundle")
        }
```

Here is the validation bundle at of course in layout i am calling the jquery 3.1.0 plugin

```
name: 'validatejsbundle',
    files: [
        'scripts/jquery.validate.js',
        'scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js'
    ]
```

Comment: What do you mean _return false on form submit_?

Comment: I mean it is not submiting the form and when I tried $('form').Valid() it always return false in chrome developer tool

Comment: Then the values you have entered are not valid.

Comment: @stephen, I tried these are also 
var validator = $("form").validate()
validator.errorList --- return empty array

$('#form').find("input.error") -- return empty array
so how to know what is wrong value

Comment: We have no idea what values you are entering in the textboxes. Your comments indicate your using some jQuery, yet there is nothing in your question about that. No one can answer this unless you explain what is actually happening under what conditions

Comment: Look I am using the asp.net mvc along with the jquery validation with unobtrusive validation, so i mentioned the jquery. and what ever value I entered in the textboxes it never succeed the validation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124734/discussion-between-chitta-and-stephen-muecke).

Comment: @stephen, when ever i entered any wrong values like if there is mismatch in both the fields then it is showing message but even after entering same value in both the fields the form niether display any error message any more nor submits the form

Comment: Keep the comments to chat :)

Answer (score -1):

Problem was with the version of the validation and unobtrusive. I was using(jQuery.Validation.Unobtrusive.2.0.20710.0) the jquery one but now I am using the Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation.3.2.3 and all seems working fine now.